# How is this parse tree generated?

Tags: context-free-grammar, parse-tree

I was reading [https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs390/f16/Public/cfg/index.html](https://www.cs.odu.edu/%7Ezeil/cs390/f16/Public/cfg/index.html) and came across this example grammar:

```
Expr -> Expr + Term  
Expr -> Expr - Term  
Expr -> Term  
Term -> Term * Factor  
Term -> Term/Factor  
Factor -> (Expr)  
Factor -> id
```

Using this grammar, the following parse tree is given for the string "a - b - c":

[image: parse tree]

My question is, how are the Factor non-terminals being produced from Term non-terminals? I don't see how this is done in the grammar. To me it would seem that the grammar needs an extra production rule like Term -> Factor.

Comment: What you're saying sounds reasonable to me, but I wonder if this question would be better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are right. It's missing a production: "Term -> Factor". See the Dragon book for how it's done right.

Comment: @kaby76: maybe you could make that an answer.

Comment: @rici I'll skip. I get downvoted for just about everything, so I just don't offer "answers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely correct. The grammar is missing the production `Term ⇒ Factor`, as can be seen in the parse tree.